# show that the limit does not exist: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Show that the following limit does not exist:
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$$ 
>   $(x>0)$

The $\delta$ - $\varepsilon$ definition can be used to prove a given limit exists for some function at a particular point. My question is, can we prove the non-existence of a limit using the $\delta$ - $\varepsilon$ definition? (A little hint on how, if yes.)
Besides that, what (other) methods can we use?

[SIMILAR POST: [Can we prove that there is no limit at $x=0$ for $f(x)=1/x$ using epsilon-delta definition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147623/can-we-prove-that-there-is-no-limit-at-x-0-for-fx-1-x-using-epsilon-delta) ]

Comment: It does exist though.

Comment: The limit exists but is $+\infty$: to see this consider simply $\limsup$ and $\liminf$: the same is true even if you consider the whole $\mathbb{R}$ instead of the positive axis. Perhaps the standard terminology is a bit hazy since in such cases it is said that the function *diverges*: however this does not mean tha the limit does not exists, but simply that the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Show that for every $L>0$ and $\varepsilon=1\;\exists\:\delta>0$, $|f(x)-L|>\varepsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is asserted is that there is no finite limit. Prove by contradiction. Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1 {x^{2}}=L$ exists and is finite. Then we can find $\delta >0$ such that $|\frac 1 {x^{2}}-L|<1$ whenever $0<x<\delta$. If $n$ is any sufficiently large integer then  $0<\frac  1 n<\delta$ so, taking $x=\frac 1 n$ we get $| n^{2}-L|<1$. This gives $n^{2} <L+1$ for any sufficiently large integer $n$ which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: Why would you take $x = \frac{1}{n}$, if by definition $x$ should belong to the open interval $(- \frac{1}{n},  \frac{1}{n})$?